# Mocking a http response using vert.x rxjava2 and Mockito

Tags: mockito, rx-java2, vert.x

I'm playing with the rxjava vert.x (ver. 3.8.4) WebClient. My client will call some services so, by Mockito (ver. 3.2.4) I'm testing how it should handle an error. Here is how I mock the service's response:

```
...
JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();
HttpResponse<Buffer> httpResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse.class);
Mockito.when(httpResponse.statusCode()).thenReturn(500);
Mockito.when(httpResponse.bodyAsJsonObject()).thenReturn(jsonResponse);
HttpRequest<Buffer> httpRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpRequest.class);
Mockito.when(httpRequest.rxSend()).thenReturn(Single.just(httpResponse));
return httpRequest;
...
```

as the `Mockito.when(httpResponse.statusCode()).thenReturn(500);` is executed I get this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at my.dummy.project.ServiceHandlerTest.serviceRepliesWithA500Response(ServiceHandlerTest.java:70)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use okhttp's MockWebServer for this kind of test case.

MockWebserver can be instantiated for each test and will allow you to create a webservice url that can be used by your implementation under test to send a real http request against it.

Before that you can define a mock response that will be returned by the mockwebserver to your implementation.

I don't know your test case, but this snippet should make clear how MockWebServer works.

More examples and the full docu can be found at [their github repo](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

As you can see below, you can make a couple of assertions, eg. if the correct request method has been used, how many requests were fired and if the correct request parameters and body were used during the request.

```java
    @ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
    @Slf4j
    public class WebServiceTest {

        private WebServiceRequester sut;

        private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            sut = new WebServiceRequester();
            mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        }

        @Test
        public void testCallService(final Vertx vertx, final VertxTestContext testContext) throws InterruptedException {
            // given
            final JsonObject requestPayload = new JsonObject().put("requestData", new JsonArray("[]"));
            final JsonObject serverResponsePayload = new JsonObject().put("responseData", new JsonArray("[]"));
            mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                                      .setBody(serverResponsePayload.encode())
                                      .setResponseCode(200)
                                      .setHeader("content-type", "application/json"));

            // when
            final String webServiceUrl = mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
            final Promise<String> stringPromise =
                sut.callService(
                    webServiceUrl,
                    requestPayload,
                    vertx);

            // then
            final RecordedRequest recordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest();
            assertEquals("POST", recordedRequest.getMethod());
            assertEquals("[text={\"request\":[]}]", recordedRequest.getBody().toString());
            assertEquals(1, mockWebServer.getRequestCount());
            testContext.assertComplete(stringPromise.future())
                       .map(val -> {
                           assertEquals("promise_completed", val);
                           testContext.completeNow();
                           return val;
                       })
                       .onComplete(onComplete -> {
                           assertTrue(onComplete.succeeded());
                           log.info("done");
                       })
                       .onFailure(onError -> Assertions.fail());

        }
    }
```

Comment: MockWebServer is a 'nice-to-have' for sure!